# Service worker error: event already responded to

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, service-worker, service-worker-events

I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The event has already been responded to.

I know that service workers automatically respond if asynchronous stuff goes on within the fetch function, but I can't quite work out which bit would be the offender in this code:

```
importScripts('cache-polyfill.js');

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

  var location = self.location;

  console.log("loc", location)

  self.clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true}).then(clients => {
    for (const client of clients) {
      const clientUrl = new URL(client.url);
      console.log("SO", clientUrl);
      if(clientUrl.searchParams.get("url") != undefined && clientUrl.searchParams.get("url") != '') {
        location = client.url;
      }
    }

  console.log("loc2", location)

  var url = new URL(location).searchParams.get('url').toString();

  console.log(event.request.hostname);
  var toRequest = event.request.url;
  console.log("Req:", toRequest);

  var parser2 = new URL(location);
  var parser3 = new URL(url);

  var parser = new URL(toRequest);

  console.log("if",parser.host,parser2.host,parser.host === parser2.host);
  if(parser.host === parser2.host) {
    toRequest = toRequest.replace('https://booligoosh.github.io',parser3.protocol + '//' +  parser3.host);
    console.log("ifdone",toRequest);
  }

  console.log("toRequest:",toRequest);

  event.respondWith(httpGet('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + toRequest));
  });
});

function httpGet(theUrl) {
    /*var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;*/
    return(fetch(theUrl));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `event.respondWith()` is inside your top-level promise's `.then()` clause, meaning that it  will be asynchronously executed after the top-level promise resolves. In order to get the behavior you're expecting, `event.respondWith()` needs to execute synchronously as part of the `fetch` event handler's execution.

The logic inside of your promise is a bit hard to follow, so I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but in general you can follow this pattern:

```
self.addEventListerner('fetch', event => {
  // Perform any synchronous checks to see whether you want to respond.
  // E.g., check the value of event.request.url.
  if (event.request.url.includes('something')) {
    const promiseChain = doSomethingAsync()
      .then(() => doSomethingAsyncThatReturnsAURL())
      .then(someUrl => fetch(someUrl));
      // Instead of fetch(), you could have called caches.match(),
      // or anything else that returns a promise for a Response.

    // Synchronously call event.respondWith(), passing in the
    // async promise chain.
    event.respondWith(promiseChain);
  }
});
```

That's the general idea. (The code looks even cleaner if you end up replacing promises with `async`/`await`.)

Answer (score 18):

I also stumbled upon this error while trying to use async/await within a fetch handler. As Jeff mentioned in his answer, `event.respondWith` has to be called synchronously and the parameter can be anything that returns a promise that resolves to a response. Since async functions do return a promise, all you have to do is wrap the fetch logic inside an async function which, at some point, returns a response object and call `event.respondWith` with that handler.

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const response = await fetch(request)

  // ...perform additional logic

  return response
}

self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});
```