# Service Worker: The event handler is already finished (even though called synchronously from the event handler)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have read and think I understand:

- [What does event.waitUntil do in service worker and why is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902441/what-does-event-waituntil-do-in-service-worker-and-why-is-it-needed)
- [Service worker error: event already responded to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838778/service-worker-error-event-already-responded-to)

The just of those answers is that `event.waitUntil()` must be called synchronously from the event handler. Which is what I am doing below (in fact it is the only line of the event handler):

The Error

```js
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The event handler is already finished.
```

Min reproducible example:

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => event.waitUntil(handleFetch(event)));

async function handleFetch(event) {
    const response = await runFetch(event);
    event.respondWith(response);  // <---- here the error is raised
}

async function runFetch(event) {
    const response = await fetch(event.request.url);

    if (response.ok) {
        // Don't await cachePut, allow the response to be returned immediately first.
        // Then later it will perform the cachePut promise. Use waitUntil so the Service worker is not killed until the cachePut promise resolves.
        event.waitUntil(cachePut(event.request.url, response.clone()));
    }
    return response
}

async function cachePut(url, response) {
    const cache = await caches.open('my-cache');
    await cache.put(url, response)
}
```

Note: It seems okay to call `waitUntil` multiple times (calling `waitUntil` in a nested sense for cachePut): [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil):

> The waitUntil() method must be initially called within the event callback, but after that it can be called multiple times, until all the promises passed to it settle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a code comment explaining why the cache put is not awaited. Wish to have the response returned immediately, and the cachePut to happen in the background later, but let the browser know not to kill the SW before it has finished the cache put.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the clarification, I added an `await` inside `cachePut`, good find!

Comment: :-) I take it that didn't solve the problem though. (I didn't really think it would, but you never know...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder =) It didnt solve the problem, but probably prevented a second question! Thanks again!

Comment: Instead of `event.waitUntil(cachePut(event.request.url, response.clone()))` could is also just write `await cachePut(...)`. As long as I return promises I would not need nested `waitUntil` right?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:
`respondWith` wait before ending the .event
`waitUntil` wait before killing the service worker.

The differences between `respondWith` and `waitUntil` seem obvious at first, but the context is slightly different. If one uses `respondWith`, then `waitUntil` is implicit, i.e. can't respond until `respondWith` completes.

Originally I would bypass the Service worker and not use `respondWith` in some situations, but I guess then it doesnt know I am still figuring out whether to respond or not, and assumes the event is done. So if I wish to bypass the SW, I just `return fetch(event.request)`, and use `respondWith` instead.

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => { event.respondWith(handleFetch2(event)) });

async function handleFetch2(event) {
    const response = await runFetch2(event);
    return response;
}

async function cachePut2(url, response) {
    const cache = await caches.open('my-cache');
    await cache.put(url, response)
}

async function runFetch2(event) {
    const response = await fetch(event.request.url);

    if (response.ok) {
        event.waitUntil(cachePut2(event.request.url, response.clone()));
    }
    return response
}
```